# The Text inside <Text> tag does not show up on screen in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and was following a tutorial. For some reason, the text in the <Text> tag inside <View> does not show up on the screen when I set flex:1 for the container. But when I comment it out I can see the text.

[image: Image of virtual screen]

Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

export default function SignInScreen(){
    return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>

            <View style ={{marginLeft:20, marginTop:10}}>
                 <Text style = {styles.title}>Sign-In</Text>
            </View>

            <View style = {{alignItems:"center",marginTop:10}}>
                <Text style = {styles.text1}>Please Enter email address</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1
    },
    title: {
        color:"#ff8c52",
        fontSize :20,
        fontWeight:"bold"
    },
    text1: {
        color: "#ff8c52",
        fontSize:16
    }
})
```

Can someone explain why this is so?

Comment: Try ```justifyContent: 'center'``` for your container.

Comment: @DanielOlsen It's still the same. The text doesn't show up until I remove flex:1.

Comment: Does the parent component have flex as well? If the parent has no volume, then the child will have nothing to fill with flex. Try adding flex to the parent.

Comment: @groteworld Thank you it works now. This was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox fills the area that its parent gives it, so make sure that the parent component also uses flex or has a volume to it.